# Nginx won't serve the json responses

Tags: nginx

I've got a single page application running on a server correctly, serving pages across different urls:

- example.com
- example.com/jsonendpoint

But when I try to access an endpoint meant to return JSON, I get an HTML response. The nginx config looks like:

```
server {
    root /home/myapplication/server/public;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://myapplication/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /jsonendpoint {
    proxy_pass http://myapplication/;
    default_type application/json;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

If I comment out the `try_files` line, then the JSON response works fine and I can still access the root URL at `example.com` but when I try to access `example.com/jsonendpoint` then nginx returns a 404.

How do I fix the config to get both things to work?

**EDIT**:

When I curl the server from within the VPS it's hosted on:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:3000/jsonendpoint
```

I get a JSON response:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

When I make the same curl request from my local machine (which means going through nginx then the response type is wrong:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

This rules out the possibility that the problem lies with the backend server.

The `mime.types` file does have the json mime type added and it is being included by nginx. I've also tried forcing a response type per location block (see above snippet).

Answer (score 2):

Check that in your in your [mime types](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/mime.types) you have something like:

```
application/json      json;
```

Then try to query your site using something like this:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://your-site
```

Check for the header `content-type` if your application is returning json it should be:

```
content-type: application/json
```

If you get something like:

```
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Check your backend to add the proper content type.

In case you would like to force the type, try this:

```
location / {
    default_type application/json;
    # ...
}
```

Comment: no bueno. I've updated the question with some additional details

Comment: @Simpleton what’s the output “content type” of the proxy_pass url you are passing?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but wanted to share what fixed the issue for me:

nginx-user did not have access to my json files. Apparently root-user loads you the html when you browse to website. But other requests like json calls will be served in nginx worker threads as nginx-user.

I added read and execute permissions to all users in html-folder to solve this problem (there are maybe better solutions also):

```
chmod -R 755 /usr/share/nginx/html
```